# call component Listener manually

Tags: java, swing

I add a listener to JCheckBox component and I want call listener manually.how do it?

```
myCheckBox.selected(false)
```

then I want to called myCheckBox listener. Do you have better idea?

Comment: should happen automatically - if not, please show an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: please specify when you want to call listener and please provide some more information and SSCCE(Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm a bit late, but this should do the trick:

```
ItemListener listener = new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
         //whatever your itemStateChanged() looks like.
    }
};
JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
checkBox.addItemListener(listener);
```

Then, whenever you need to call it manually:

```
listener.itemStateChanged(
                new ItemEvent(checkBox, ItemEvent.ITEM_STATE_CHANGED, checkBox, 0));
```

If you created your listener anonymously, you can still access it like:

```
checkBox.getItemListeners()[0].itemStateChanged(
                new ItemEvent(checkBox, ItemEvent.ITEM_STATE_CHANGED, checkBox, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what checkBox component you use. You don't tell us which framework do you use or provide other helpful context infos.

But in general: Your listener is impl. an interface. This interface defines the callbackmethod that your component (checkBox) calls.

If you have a instance of your listener obj. you can call this method directly.

Comment: I used JCheckBox.I add ItemListener and Override its itemStateChange.

Comment: Just call the itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) method on your ItemListener as mentioned above. You need an instance of itemEvent if your implementations uses the given reference. Otherwise just provide null.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to call the Listener, why not just use a separate method?

```
ItemListener listener = new ItemListener() {
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
      method();
   }
};
public void method() {
   //code you want to run
}
```

Then just call `method()` when you want to run the code separate from the Listener.

Comment: Oh, I guess I'm a bit late as well. Just checked the date the question was posted...